# Wordpress running on nginx on a subdomain doesn't work on port 80

Tags: php, django, wordpress, nginx

I have a server hosting two Django websites and a wordpress blog, all on nginx. I have setup one Django site to be served at the top level domain, and the other at a subdomain.

I have not been able to get the Wordpress site to work when it is on port 80. If I change the port to 8079, it works correctly.

Here is my nginx conf for the Wordpress site:

```
server {
    listen   80;

    root /var/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name sub2.mydomain.com;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
          root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            # With php5-fpm:
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
             }


}
```

One thing I have noticed is that even after I change the port back to 80 and restart nginx, when I go to the url in my web browser, it will redirect to port 8079. I'm not sure if that is caused by the browser cache, or DNS or something on my server.

Here are my other nginx configs:

```
 upstream mydomain_app_server {
    server unix:/webapps/mydomain/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name www.mydomain.com;
    client_max_body_size 4G;

    access_log /webapps/mydomain/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /webapps/mydomain/logs/nginx-error.log;

    location /static/ {
        alias /webapps/mydomain/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /webapps/mydomain/media/;
    }

location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

    proxy_redirect off;

    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        proxy_pass http://mydomain_app_server;
        break;
    }
}

    # Error pages
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
        root /webapps/mydomain/static/;
    }
}
```

and my last one is identical except with different paths and the following server_name:

```
server_name  sub2.mydomain.com;
```

Comment: I would think this is a wordpress site url issue. Do you know what the wordpress absolute url is? It sounds like it would be something like "localhost:8079" and not just "localhost".

Comment: Can you show your other nginx config files?

Comment: @ESPmorph I have not set a wordpress url inside wp-config.php. Is there anywhere else this would be set?

Comment: Its usually set in the database. Sorry, I'm here for the django.